# Create a specific number of new variables depending on the value of existing variables

Tags: r

I'd like to create a new vector. I have data in the following structure:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,1,3,4,1,5,7,3,3,7,4), nrow=6, ncol=2)
```

I'd like to create a vector which is made in the following way:

For each row:

- If observation in column 1 is equal to 1, create a single variable equal to the observation in column 2
- If " " " " " " " 2, create 2 variables equal to the observation in column 2
- If " " " " " " " 3, create 3 variables ...
  etc.

Using my example matrix A, I would end up with a vector B as follows:

```
B <- matrix(c(5,7,7,3,3,3,3,7,7,7,7,4),nrow=12,ncol=1)
```

So you end up with a vector as long as the sum of column 1 in the original matrix.

Could anyone help with some simple code to generate B from A?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do what you want with `rep`:

```
rep(A[, 2], A[, 1])
 # [1] 5 7 7 3 3 3 3 7 7 7 7 4
```

Comment: Nice, I did not know you could use vectors as arguments in `rep`. Learned something new again :)

Comment: This is surely a very good approach

Comment: I feel safer with `rep(A[, 2], times = A[, 1])` even though it is the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, @Cath! Nice simple solution that works perfectly :-) Jess

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
unlist(sapply(1:nrow(A),function(x) rep(A[x,2],A[x,1])))
```